# Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'isEmailVerification'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

i have a litle problem when i configurate a start session on my app and this is: "Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'isEmailVerification'"

```
func signIn(email:String?, password:String?) {
    if email == nil || password == nil {
        showAlert(title: "Login Error!", message: "All fields are required.")
    } else {
        SwiftLoader.show(animated: true)

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email!, password: password!) { (user, error) in
            SwiftLoader.hide()

            if let err = error {
                self.showAlert(title: "Login Error!", message: err.localizedDescription)
            } else  {
                if (user?.isEmailVerification){ //error:"Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'isEmailVerification'"
                    self.sendEmailVerification()
                }else{
                    self.showAlert(title: "", message: "Has iniciado sesión correctamente")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the return is of type `AuthDataResult` that contains the user object `FIRUser`

```
user?.user.isEmailVerified
```

you better rename the callback to avoid reading confusion see here in Docs

[AuthDataResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/AuthDataResult)

[FIRUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRUser)